# How does one debug a production Angular2/Typescript app?

Tags: javascript, debugging, angular, typescript

I am embarking on building a new app using Angular2 and Typescript, never having used either of the technologies together before (but have used them separately, so I have some experience).

My question is how does one debug client end of the application given that Typescript compiler converts your code to JavaScript and I end up with a ton of machine generated code (which at times *looks* like machine generated code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript is a transpiler that can also generate source maps for you. Typescript output isn't too different to to the source itself. You can always just debug the js files.

However if you had a large bundled js file and wanted do debug individual ts files, you need to export source maps.

Typescript has a couple of sourceMapping flags. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

All current web browsers can load source maps and map breakpoints back to the source files.

You can bundle the source map and sources as part of your .js file. (NOTE: This will make the js files a lot bigger)

`tsc --sourceMap --inlineSources --inlineSourceMaps`

Alternatively if your webserver can serve the source .ts files and .map files you can set

`tsc --sourceMap --sourceRoot <root of src>`

The second option results js files with an extra sourceMappingUrl comment at the end but the devtools of the browser has to lookup the .map file and the source files.

Comment: Source is not different in many places, but is different in many others where I am utilizing TypeScript features that are not present in JS2015.  Example: https://i.imgur.com/xTbJbVE.png  But point well taken - I'll try and use source maps.

Answer (score 0):

You can log messages and data to the browser console as usual, and set breakpoints in the machine-generated javascript using your browser's developer tools. The generated code is not significantly indistinguishable from your Typescript code - it is different but you should be able to determine what piece of your code you are looking at. Hope this Helps